# Writing infinity to feature class in ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy

Is it possible to write infinities to fields in ArcGIS feature classes, and if so, how?

Currently I get an exception thrown when I try.

Comment: what are you trying, and what is your exception?

Comment: Normally it's `float("-inf"), float("inf")` for Python >= 2.6

Comment: Thanks guys.  I was trying to call `row.setValue(field,float("inf"))` (well, effectively anyway) where `row` was an UpdateCursor on a feature class in a file geodatabase.  Jakub's answer looks good to me - looks like anything that might happen to work isn't officially supported!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Float in ArcGIS has a range of values**. Infinity values are not supported. You can store such values in 3rd party non ESRI applications and attempt to import but these values will be changed to 1.#INF -1.#INF and you may encounter problems with Querying, etc.

Check out [Referring to NaN or ±∞ (special floating point values) in ArcMap definition queries?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20372/in-esri-arcmap-how-do-i-refer-to-nan-or-special-floating-point-values-in-d) for more info.

Sources:

http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//003n0000001m000000

http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/25646